# for each inside a for each - Java

Tags: java, android, for-loop

```
for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {                
    for(long forId : idFromArray){
        long tweetId = tweet.getId();
        if(forId != tweetId){
            String twitterString = tweet.getText();
            db.insertTwitter(twitterString, tweetId);
        }
    }
}
```

My code won't run pass the first for{} loop, that's why idFromArray is empty since I don't add anything there until a tweet is has been added to the database.

And even if there is something in the array it loops the whole thing twice (DUH! Since I have two loops) which makes the database very bloated with the same tweets.

It is not a simple compare of the two tweets id and simply ignore the ones with the same id.

I'm pretty certain there is a really simple solution to this problem, but I still can't wrap my head around it. Anybody?

**UPDATE:**

What I want is the code to ignore the the tweetId that already is in the database.
And just insert the tweets that is not in the database.

I don't think I should have two for-loops, I think the second loop should be replaced with something? (or maybe I'm wrong?)

Comment: Why don't you start with explaining what you want to do? Clearly you are looking for an algorithm and not something to do with how the for-loop works.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do, in pseudo-code is the following:

```
for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
    if (!db.containsTweet(tweet.getId())) {
        db.insertTweet(tweet.getText(), tweet.getId());
    }
}
```

I assume your db class actually uses an sqlite database as a backend? What you could do is implement `containsTweet` directly and just query the database each time, but that seems less than perfect. The easiest solution if we go by your base code is to just keep a `Set` around that indexes the tweets. Since I can't be sure what the `equals()` method of `Tweet` looks like, I'll just store the identifiers in there. Then you get:

```
Set<Integer> tweetIds = new HashSet<Integer>(); // or long, whatever
for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
    if (!tweetIds.contains(tweet.getId())) {
        db.insertTweet(tweet.getText(), tweet.getId());
        tweetIds.add(tweet.getId());
    }
}
```

It would probably be better to save a tiny bit of this work, by sorting the list of `tweets` to begin with and then just filtering out duplicate tweets. You could use:

```
// if tweets is a List
Collections.sort(tweets, new Comparator() {
    public int compare (Object t1, Object t2) {
        // might be the wrong way around
        return ((Tweet)t1).getId() - ((Tweet)t2).getId();
    }
}
```

Then process it

```
Integer oldId;
for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
    if (oldId == null || oldId != tweet.getId()) {
        db.insertTweet(tweet.getText(), tweet.getId());
    }
    oldId = tweet.getId();
}
```

Yes, you could do this using a second for-loop, but you'll run into performance problems much more quickly than with this approach (although what we're doing here is trading time for memory performance, of course).

Comment: I think I just became a better programmer. Thanks wds!

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is not correct. It should be like that:

```
for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {              
    for(long forId : idFromArray){
        long tweetId = tweet.getId();
        if(forId != tweetId){
            String twitterString = tweet.getText();
            db.insertTwitter(twitterString);
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

This answer no longer really answers the question since it was updated ;)

Comment: Hey is it not the same that I wrote?, maybe I'm blind :P

Comment: First foreach, you are missing a "tweet". You only have the class Tweet but you also need a tweet Object. Happens to me all the time.

Comment: This is actually what I wrote in the code, but since i slimmed it down in the example that somehow got lost too. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

most simple solution would be to set a boolean var. if to true where you do the insert statement and then in the outter loop check this and insert the tweet there if the boolean is true...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Tweet : tweets){ ...
```

should really be

```
for(Tweet tweet: tweets){...
```

Answer (score 0):

So you really want:

```
for each tweet
    unless tweet is in db
        insert tweet
```

If so, just write it down in your programming language.
Hint: The loop over the array is to be done before the insert, which is done depending on the outcome.

What you want to test is that *all* array elements are not equal to the current one. But your for loop does not do that.